# Is it legal to link or embed somebody else's content if I give credit?

Tags: copyright, internet, intellectual-property, licensing

I want to embed [this website](https://ruwix.com/widget/notation/) as part of a website. If the website is commercial am I allowed to do this if I credit them?

If not, is it legal just to link to them as part of tutorial page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assume everything on the web - text, images, designs and code - is copyrighted, because (mostly) it is by default under [Universal Copyright Convention - Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Copyright_Convention)

And most sites have terms and conditions of your use of the site that you agree to by accessing the site; it's a good idea to look for a "Terms of Service" (TOS) or other such document when you have questions about the content or use of any website.

Read [Terms and Conditions/Privacy Policy - Ruwix](https://ruwix.com/terms-and-conditions-privacy-policy/) linked at the bottom of each page:

> The Ruwix Plugins on this website are copyrighted and can be embedded
>   in other websites only using the iframe codes provided by us.

The Ruwix site terms say you can embed their widgets only by using their iFrames, which means they retain control of the display on your site and control how their copyright notice appears and how their website is linked.

The site's terms *do not say you can embed the entire site* by iFrame. They do say that

> Unauthorized use of this website may give rise to a claim for damages
>   and/or be a criminal offence.

And Rumix can choose to change the terms to reflect that embedding the entire site by iFrame is an unauthorized use.

The legality of embedding an entire site is complicated: see [Copyright aspects of hyperlinking and framing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_aspects_of_hyperlinking_and_framing#Framing).

Re: your second question: plain text hyperlinking (or even linking via image, ad, inline text, etc.) from one site to other pages and sites is not a copyright violation (see link above); if it was, the entire [Hypertext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext) design of the internet would be called into question.

Comment: There is case law that says linking is not a copyright violation. Embedding is a very different issue.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had answered the second part, but hadn't.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! The only thing I would be unsure about with linking is if you have a paid service linking to them because then they would technically be paying for the link to the site along with the other content

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean or who would be paying whom. It sounds like paid ads or native advertising, which isn't an illegal type of linking.

Comment: @Booligoosh I paid Stackexchange $0.00 to create this link to [Google](http://www.google.com). Even if I did pay for the link, it is not copyright infringement because I didn't copy Google's copyrighted content to make the link.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch no as in it is part of a tutorial that the user pays for, so this is [sort of] part of the content